# How will COVID travel restrictions affect postdoctoral hiring this year?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, covid-19

As concern for the Omicron variant rises, and travel restrictions resume, how will this affect academic hiring decisions in this application cycle? Does this mean there will be work visa issues? Will domestic applicants be viewed differently than international applicants?

Comment: Much of the future troubles are very difficult to anticipate accurately this far back. Hard to guess what circumstances will be by the end of next summer, just prior to the beginning of fall term in the U.S.  Things are so unclear that it's hard even to see what "risk averse" could mean, usefully.

Comment: It is difficult to predict, especially the future.

Comment: Anecdotal data point: I waited about five months to be issued a Spanish visa earlier this year, but whether that was to do with Brexit, Covid or simply the usual crushingly slow speed of Spanish bureaucracy, who can say...

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to say and it will probably vary by region. The new variant may not be the last and it is unlikely that it will be. There is a lot of vaccine resistance and misinformation.

Unfortunately, the pressures to ignore the problem and just "return to normal" can (and have) make the problem worse. But visas may be hard to get.

Hope for the best, but plan for the worst.